# Is there an api to get the network interface's unique id of a CM in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

In Compute Engine VM Instances, is there an api to get the unique id of each network interface, because in VM metadata, all I get is the api for VPC network.

Comment: What do you mean by "unique id"?  Can you provide an example?

Comment: Like for disk and instance, there will be an id provided by GCP right (instance id)

Comment: Network interfaces are not their own resource but a property of an instance. As such, they do not have an ID (not even internally).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the network interfaces are properties of a Compute Engine instances.  If, for example, we have a compute engine with the name "demo1" and run the gcloud command:

```
gcloud compute instances describe --zone=us-central1-a demo1
```

we find the following in the results:

```
... snip ...
networkInterfaces:
- accessConfigs:
  - kind: compute#accessConfig
    name: External NAT
    natIP: 35.224.168.99
    networkTier: PREMIUM
    type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT
  fingerprint: BkeolfdxI4A=
  kind: compute#networkInterface
  name: nic0
  network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/YOUR-PROJECT/global/networks/default
  networkIP: 10.128.0.2
  subnetwork: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/YOUR-PROJECT/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default
... snip ...
```

as such, the unique id for a network interface could be constructed from the unique id of the Compute Engine instance concatenated with the name of the network interface:

`6817424148295517299_nic0`

Answer (score -1):

If you need to retrieve information from your VM instances in your project such as status,IPs or Network Interface names you can use the Compute Engine API specifically the method instances.get , please see [1] for detailed documentation and a widget to test it on the top right corner.

The output will be similar to

"networkInterfaces": [
  {
   "kind": "compute#networkInterface",
   "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT/global/networks/default",
   "subnetwork": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT/regions/YOUR_REGION/subnetworks/default",
   "networkIP": "X.X.X.X",
   "name": "NIC_NAME",
   "accessConfigs": [
    {
     "kind": "compute#accessConfig",
     "type": "ONE_TO_ONE_NAT",
     "name": "EXTERNAL_NIC_NAME",
     "natIP": "X.X.X.X",
     "networkTier": "PREMIUM"
    }

You will need the following information to run this command.

1)Project ID
2)Zone of the instance
3)Name of the instance

You can get your project ID by following the steps below.

1)Visit www.cloud.google.com
2) Login with your account
3) Click on the arrow next to your project name (blue banner at the top)
4)A pop-up window will open with the “ID” column

Please visit [2] to see the requisites to use the Compute Engine API.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get
[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/prereqs